# PHP delete user favourites

Tags: php, html, mysql

I developed a system for users to favourite their favourite pages. Of course, I need a way to delete them. Only problem is, I can't get it to work. Any ideas what I can do? My current code is this:

```
<?php
    $username="user";$password="pass";$database="DB ";
    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
    mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
    $query="SELECT * FROM `faves` WHERE userid = $userid";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);mysql_close();
?>




<?php
$i=0;while ($i < $num) {$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"link");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");?>
<ul>
<li>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo '<a href="'.$f1.'">'.$f2.'</a>
<br /> 
 <form action="/scripts/delete.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id"
  value="'.$f3.'"
    <input type="submit" value="delete" /> 
</form>'
; ?></font>



<?php mysqli_close(mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error())); $i++;} ?>
</li>
</ul>
```

This works fine for displaying links to users' favourite pages, but not a way to delete. I'm stumped as to what to do (as you see, I tried using a form but that doesn't work).

Table variables:

```
id = row Id
link = link to the favourited page
name = name of favourite page
userid = user's ID
```

Comment: First of all, don't mix mysqli and mysql

`<?php mysqli_close(mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error())); $i++;} ?>`

Comment: Oops, yeah, I've changed it back to mysql now.
I'll update to using PDO or whatever when I get a VPS (my current server still uses version 5.3.28 and I can't upgrade)

Comment: please post code in scripts/delete.php

Comment: delete.php hasn't been made yet. The issue was, my form wasn't even showing.

I've just changed the form about a bit and everything is working now. Not sure what was wrong (maybe a HTML syntax error?). Should I post an answer to my own question now?

Comment: In fact, looking back at my question, I see the issue. I forgot to put `/>` at the end of the hidden input type! Doh!

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query in `scripts/delete.php` should look something like this:

```
DELETE FROM `faves` WHERE id = INSERT_ROW_ID_HERE
```

Also, remove the following piece of code:

```
mysqli_close(mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()));
```

It doesn't make any sense and MySQL connections are automatically closed as soon as the script finishes.

Comment: I put that there because I used a similar piece of code in another page because the connection wasn't being closed, causing everything else not to work :/

Answer (score 0):

use belwo logic:
1: add something like bookmark
2:when user click that use ajax to save that in databse with user id
3: ajax to delete same with user id